# Listing all folders in a directory, ignoring any other files

Tags: python

How would you return a list of folders inside a directory? I just need their names. I know about `glob.glob` to list everything in a directory but I don't know how to filter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# Set root to whatever directory you want to check
root= os.getcwd()
dirlist = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
print (dirlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might combine *list comprehension* with some functions from `os` to print folders inside current catalog following way:

```
import os
folders = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if os.path.isdir(i)]
print(folders)
```

where:

- `os.getcwd` gets current working directory
- `os.listdir` returns list of everything inside given directory
- `os.path.isdir` checks if i is directory

if you wish to do this for another catalog than current directory use `os.chdir('path_to_your_catalog')` after `import os`.